# Integrating Ember_simple_auth with acceptance tests (using Mirage)

Tags: ember.js, ember-simple-auth, ember-cli-mirage

I created a basic test app that uses the OMDb API (The Open Movie Database), and with [some help from SO posters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35633010/ember-tests-mirage-not-finding-dom-elements) everything is working fine.

I added ember-simple-auth (version 1.0.0) to the project, and got the dev side of things going. Basically there's a simple login screen to get into the main app. It's working as expected.

However, my two basic acceptance tests are now not working. After adding the ember-simple-auth components and functionality to the app, to the acceptance test file I added:

```
import { currentSession, authenticateSession, invalidateSession } from 'movie-example/tests/helpers/ember-simple-auth';
```

and in a test itself, I added:

```
authenticateSession();
```

The test now fails, saying:

```
Cannot read property '__container__' of undefined
```

Moreover, if I comment out the import line and the authenticateSession() call, the test still fails, but because the DOM is apparently completely empty.

The whole thing is available in a repo if anyone is curious/willing: git@github.com:bdrsgg/ember-movie-example.git (branch = feature/ember-simple-auth)

I assume there's some configuration issue I'm getting wrong, or something like that. Appreciate any help anyone can offer.

**EDITED TO ADD:**

The issue definitely seems to center on authentication. For example, if I remove the AuthenticatedRouteMixin calls from the routes, and leave out authenticateSession() calls, the tests pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out I was just not declaring an earlier application variable correctly. Long story short, when I changed authenticateSession() to authenticateSession(this.application), things worked as expected.